# Is there a self-hosted google-sites like solution?

Tags: wiki

I am looking for a wiki type software to keep something like a wiki/knowledge base at my university. I tried MediaWiki (with FCKeditor), DokuWiki and MoinMoin, but they seem too hard to use for an average user - at least not without some trouble.

I found Google Sites to be almost ideal for my purpose, but as I mentioned the wiki is to be used at my university, there will be a strong demand to host it on our servers.

Do you know any software similar to what Google Sites offers? What I really want is a WYSIWYG editor and a hierarchical menu structure - without cryptic "categories" or lots of colons or brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, providing some hacking every **CMS** (Drupal, Joomla, Wordpres...) could help you.
You (the developer) just have to build the site (design, use cases, deployment...etc) according to your (University) needs: simple & intuituve UI, simple tasks..etc